# How to move non-empty values to the front of a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the array:

```
var arr = ['', 'foo', '', 'bar', '', 'baz', ''];
```

I would like to get back:

```
[ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', '', '', '', '' ]
```

Comment: This was inspired by a very simple use case in which I only have two entries in the array and would probably just `pop` the value in `[1]` off, and `unshift` it back on, but when I researched (googled) the more general problem I did not see an exact match on stackoverflow, so thought it was worth a Q&A

Answer (score 5):

I would go with a custom sort function, like this:

```
['', 'foo', '', 'bar', '', 'baz', ''].sort((a, b) => !a ? 1 : !b ? -1 : 0);
// returns: ["foo", "bar", "baz", "", "", "", ""]
```

Comment: Yeah I wondered if a custom sort would work but couldn't figure out how to do it off the top of my head, so posted my solution using filter and concat

Answer (score 0):

One non-ES6 way to do it is:

```
var arr = ['', 'foo', '', 'bar', '', 'baz', ''];
arr = arr.filter(function(val){return val}).concat(arr.filter(function(val){return !val}));
```

Or, using ES6 to shorten things:

```
arr = arr.filter((val) => val).concat(arr.filter((val) => !val));
```

Answer (score 0):

Questionable performance, but:

```js
var arr = ['', 'foo', '', 'bar', '', 'baz', ''];

arr.forEach((v, i) => v || (arr.splice(i, 1), arr.push(v)) );

console.log(arr)
```

Of course, in-place swap solution without resizing or creating extra arrays would be more efficient:

```js
var arr = ['', 'foo', '', 'bar', '', 'baz', ''];

for (var i = 0, j = arr.length - 1, v; ; ++i, --j) {
  while (arr[i]) ++i
  while (!arr[j]) --j
  if (i >= j) break
  v = arr[i]
  arr[i] = arr[j]
  arr[j] = v
}

console.log(arr)
```

Or preserving order:

```js
var arr = ['', 'foo', '', 'bar', '', 'baz', '']

for (var i = 0, j = 1, len = arr.length, v; ; ++i, ++j) {
  while (arr[i]) ++i
  while (!arr[j] && j < len) ++j
  if (j >= len) break
  v = arr[i]
  arr[i] = arr[j]
  arr[j] = v
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: The order comes out wrong in your second example, though maybe I wasn't explicit enough in stating that I wanted to retain the order of the non-empty entries

Comment: It was implied in the sample result, but preserving the order requires few more swaps (only 1 more in the sample)